# Laravel INSERT query adding got error

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have work on insert query into laravel migrate.
I try to add `http.conf` file `pdo_pgsql.so` extension

I got the following error into Command Prompt.

> PHP Warning:
>
> PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   `'mylocalpath\php\ext\pdo_pgsql.so'` - The specified module could not
>   be found.

Comment: Do you have this extension loaded in php.ini file?

Comment: What os are you using?

Comment: i use Windows 8 oprating system.